# Rails 3.2 - Getting Values from User table and saving to Resume table on Update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, best-in-place

In my Rails 3.2 web application, I have `User`, `Resume` models. For resume, we have set columns like `Name`, `Email`, `Date of Birth`, `Nationality`, `Educational Qualification`, `Experience` etc. My requirement is that after a user is created by ADMIN, the Admin should be able to see a `resume template` (HTML) where in basic details like `Name`, `Email`, `Date of Birth` etc. would be taken from USER table to display it to the ADMIN for the first time. Then using best_in_place gem, the ADMIN should be able to edit and update all the values except Name and Email (non editable fields) to the RESUME table.

How I should go ahead?

```
class Resume < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :certification_info, :dob, :educational_info, :gender, :linguistic_ability, :marital_status, :nationality, :work_experience_info
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :resume
  attr_accessible :login, :email, :name, :dob, :gender, :resume_attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :resume
end
```

How we could associate `Resume` with `User` models in routes in this case?

```
resources :users
```

Do we need to have a `resume_controller` here?

How the view could be? Should I set up a form_for for User and then field_for for Resume? But I cannot use `best_in_place` in that case, right?

Suggest a proper solution please .

Comment: Do the User table has the same fields of Resume?

Comment: @Pavan: Resume has some fields similar from User, but additional fields are also there for Resume.